# How to create default constraint dependent other column in sql server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, tsqlt

i have a table like this

tab1

```
create table tab1(ID int identity(1,1), Type varchar(10),IsValued bit)
```

tab1:

```
ID Type IsValued
----------------
1   S   1
2   R   0
3   R   0
4   S   1
5   S   1
6   R   0
7   S   1
```

instead of inserting value into IsValued column 
i want to create one constraint(NOT TRIGGER) when Type ='S' ,IsValued should be inserted as 1
and when Type ='R' ,IsValued should be inserted as 0

like : `IsValued = case when Type ='S' then 1 when Type ='R' then 0 end`

How can i achieve this..

Answer (score 4):

You want a computed column. For example:

```
CREATE TABLE tab1
(
 ID INT IDENTITY(1,1)
,[Type] VARCHAR(10)
,IsValued AS CASE [Type] WHEN 'S' THEN 1
                         WHEN 'R' THEN 0
             END
)
```

You can add to an existing table using the following syntax:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tab1 ADD IsValued AS CASE [Type] WHEN 'S' THEN 1
                                                 WHEN 'R' THEN 0
                                     END
```

You can make the column persisted by adding the keyword `PERSISTED` after the column creation. Persisting the column means that the field is stored on disk. When you insert or update a record, SQL server will work out the value at that point. If you don't, SQL Server will have to work it out each time you access the row. A good explanation can be found at [SQL Server 2005 Computed Column Is Persisted](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916068/sql-server-2005-computed-column-is-persisted)

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tab1 ADD IsValued AS CASE [Type] WHEN 'S' THEN 1
                                                 WHEN 'R' THEN 0
                                     END PERSISTED
```

Comment: that IsValued column added newly into that table
using like:
alter table tab1 add IsValued bit

Comment: @sharath I've updated my example specifically to your question

Comment: @sharath Just a small note, you may wish to add the word PERSISTED after END . Explanation here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/916068/sql-server-2005-computed-column-is-persisted

Comment: ok.. but what if that column is already present in that table.
@twoleggedhorse
getting error with this.
ALTER TABLE dbo.tab1 ALTER COLUMN IsValued AS CASE [Type] WHEN 'S' THEN 1
                                                 WHEN 'R' THEN 0
                                     END PERSISTED

Comment: @RamDas You can only alter columns with certain conditions: http://sqlserverplanet.com/ddl/alter-table-alter-column You will probably have to drop the column and then add it with the keyword. ALTER TABLE dbo.tab1 DROP COLUMN IsValued