# Is it possible to automaticly have in a row a substraction between two MYSQL variables

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to have something like this :

```
+----------+------+-----+--------+
| image_id | good | bad | result |
+----------+------+-----+--------+
|        1 |   10 |   2 |      x |
+----------+------+-----+--------+
|        2 |    4 |   1 |      y |
+----------+------+-----+--------+
```

Where x and y is calculated automaticaly to be respectively 10 - 2 and 4 - 1. (good - bad) -avoid negative number if possible-

I would like this value to change if values (good or bad) changes as well.

```
+----------+------+-----+--------+
| image_id | good | bad | result |
+----------+------+-----+--------+
|        1 |   10 |   2 |      x |
+----------+------+-----+--------+
|        2 |    4 |   1 |      y |
+----------+------+-----+--------+
```

I can do this in php but is there a way to do this directly with MYSQL ?

Comment: you can try triggers if you want column result to be updated at each good/ bad column change.

Comment: I think This answers your question. http://stackoverflow.com/a/15521681/2486343

Answer (score 1):

use this query:

```
select image_id, good, bad, GREATEST(good-bad, 0) as 'result' from tbl
```

This will calculate the difference for each row and returns the result (or 0 if the result is negative= in another column named result.

As a general rule, try to avoid to store in columns the results of calculation based entirely on other columns of the same table, expecially if the calculations are so trivial like a simple difference.

Answer (score 1):

Calculate the result and return no less than zero, so avoiding negative numbers:

```
SELECT image_id, good, bad, GREATEST(good-bad, 0) AS result from `table`;
```

Comment: This works, but the question was to store the value in the database automatically not to compute it when it's needed

Comment: It sounds to me like you want a column whose value depends on the values of others. Is this the case or do you really just want the value in your query?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply write:

```
select image_id, good, bad, (good-bad) as result from mytable
```

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is have this schema:

```
CREATE TABLE tbl (image_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, good INTEGER, bad INTEGER);
CREATE VIEW tbl_result AS SELECT image_id, good, bad, CAST(good AS INTEGER) - bad AS result FROM tbl;
```

Comment: thank it's maybe what I'm looking for. But I have "tinyint unsigned" so i got an error :p : "ERROR 1690 (22003): BIGINT UNSIGNED value is out of range" (I have a lot of 0 - 0 by the way)

Comment: @bobdylan: now it should cast to an Integer.

Comment: I changed it a little bit : CREATE VIEW tbl_result AS SELECT image_id, good, bad, IF(good >= bad, good - bad, 0) AS result FROM tbl;