# Does Persisted Computed Column need to update all rows or just affected rows?

Tags: sql-server, performance, sql-server-2008-r2, calculated-columns

In this [Stackoverflow article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/916068/sql-server-2005-computed-column-is-persisted), I understand what `Persist` mean and their advantages and disadvantages. However, I tried to research deeper but cannot find about the "update" one.

Here is my scenario (TL;DR version below): I have `Order` table and `OrderDetail` table, as in this diagram:

[image]

The `OrderDetail.Subtotal` is a computed column, with this simple fomula: `([Price]*[Quantity])`

The `Order.Total` is a computed column, with this formula: `([dbo].[CalculateOrderTotal]([ID]))`, and here is the function:

```
ALTER FUNCTION [dbo].[CalculateOrderTotal]
(
    @orderID int
)
RETURNS int
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @result int;

    SELECT @result = SUM(od.Subtotal)
    FROM OrderDetail od
    WHERE od.OrderID = @orderID;

    RETURN @result;
END
```

**TL;DR**: My `Order` and `OrderDetail` are frequently updated, but only mostly INSERTING. I also need to query it usually, though not as frequently as inserting. If I check my `Subtotal` and `Total` to be `Persist`, since most of the operations won't affect the `Subtotal` field of a row, does SQL Server know it so that the database only need to update the affected record, or it have to recompute all record of `Order` table? Is it good or bad?

P.s: I am using SQL Server 2008 in case it matters.

Comment: I am not sure if you can make the orders.total persisted.

Comment: @Tim3880 You're right! I just checked, there was this message: Computed column 'Total' in table 'Tmp_Order' cannot be persisted because the column is non-deterministic.

Comment: If you want to improve the select, make the total a normal column and update it when you insert rows to order details. If you want to improve insert/update, create a v_orders view including the totals you need.

Comment: Thank you for your nice advice! I am going to do it that way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Computed columns are calculated when they are selected.
 Persisted columns are calculated when the expressions they are calculated from are changed.
So for select performance i would suggest using persist, but for storage space not to use persist, since "regular" computed columns are not actually stored in the database.

Comment: What I need to clarify is that, if a change that will not affect the computed column value (inserting an `OrderDetail` record that would not affect `Order.Total` for example) is made, do SQL Server have to re-compute all record of `Order` table?

Comment: AFAIK Sql server will only re-calculate the values that actually need re-calculation.